# Re-use BigQuery window function partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to select multiple columns as part of a LEAD statement. This *looks* like it will be really inefficient, tripling the number of sorts and partitions required ->

```
SELECT 
    field,
    field2,
    field3,
    LEAD(field, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY field ORDER BY field ASC) AS nextField,
    LEAD(field2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY field ORDER BY field ASC) AS nextField2,
    LEAD(field3, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY field ORDER BY field ASC) AS nextField3,
FROM dataset.table
```

- Is there a better way to do this?
- Does BigQuery optimize for this at query runtime to make it efficient?

Comment: Maybe concatenate the fields into one field and then do the lead and then just split that string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Couple of points to add to Mikhail's answer:

1. Yes, BigQuery optimizes it - if window frame is the same, it will be set up only once and multiple functions will run over it.
2. You are right that it is tedious to write same frame over and over again, therefore we worked on improving BigQuery SQL dialect to make it more standard compliant, and in the near future* you will be able to write

```
SELECT 
    field,
    field2,
    field3,
    LEAD(field, 1) OVER w1 AS nextField,
    LEAD(field2, 1) OVER w1 AS nextField2,
    LEAD(field3, 1) OVER w1 AS nextField3,
FROM dataset.table
WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY field ORDER BY field ASC)
```

*Cannot really give you firm date, but this is in internal testing right now, so should not be too long.

Answer (score 3):

[Window Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) already elegant enough to express in SQL your business logic.  Even though it looks like you need to repeat `PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...` part for each respective output field of SELECT statement, I personally don't think this is big price for power that window functions give us.
By the way, you are not limited to using just the same `PARTITION BY` for all output fields - you can use whatever partition you need for each. Same for `ORDER BY`

> Does BigQuery optimize for this at query runtime to make it efficient?

You can check [Query Plan Explanation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) after running your query.
It clearly shows that BigQuery re-uses partitions no matter how many Window Functions you use. And looks like if you have few different partitions they are being cascaded. (this is also clear if you see query plan)

> Is there a better way to do this?

You can mimic window function with partitioning - by multiple ways. None of them seems to perform and/or readable/manageable as good as by using window functions

For example, below logic will produce same result (just high level logic here).
You apply `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...) as POS` to original data/table.
Than you JOIN it on itself with ON a.partition=b.partition AND a.POS = a.(POS + 1) <-- this is just logic , not implementation
So now, you will have all current values in table with alias a and all next values in table alias b

As I mentioned, above produces exactly same result as with window function, but code looks much more ugly and execution shows much more expensive